# Sales per agent, year and month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with agentID, transDate and transValue. How do I report all transValue per agent, year and month? The columns are supposed to be as follows: agentID|year|January|February... Under every month must be transValue summed up. Now I have a part of code:

```
select agentID, year(transDate), sum(transValue) as January
from operations
where month(transDate) = 01
group by agentID, year(transDate)
```

I dont know how to add the following months. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation to generate that report -

```
select agentID, year(transDate),
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 1 THEN transValue END) as January,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 2 THEN transValue END) as february,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 3 THEN transValue END) as March,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 4 THEN transValue END) as April,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 5 THEN transValue END) as May,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 6 THEN transValue END) as June,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 7 THEN transValue END) as July,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 8 THEN transValue END) as August,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 9 THEN transValue END) as Spetember,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 10 THEN transValue END) as October,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 11 THEN transValue END) as November,
       sum(CASE WHEN month(transDate) = 12 THEN transValue END) as December
  from operations
 group by agentID, year(transDate)
```

Comment: @Mariachi, always welcome.